# Conditional path in nested aggregation Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, path, conditional-statements

I have a nested field with two properties:

```
{
    "rating": 2
    "victim": [{
        "ip":  "...",
        "instanceId": "....""
    }]
}
```

I want to aggregate over the rating and get the IP or InstanceId for each document, not both in the bucket list.

What i've got so far is:

```
"__rating": {
    "terms": {"field": "rating"},
    "aggs": {
        "__hosts": {
            "nested": {"path": "victim"},
            "aggs": {
                "ips": {"terms": {"field": "victim.ip"} } ,
                "instances": {"terms": {"field": "victim.instanceId"} }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Above aggregation gets me the buckets for both fields but i need one or other.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use source filtering in elasticsearch. Add this piece of code in the top of your query:

```
"_source": {
  "includes": [ "victim.ip"]
}
```

If you want more detail about source filtering, you should [check this out](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.5/search-request-source-filtering.html).

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of searching, i found the way to do it via painless script:

```
"terms" : {
    "script" : {
        "source": "doc['victim.instanceId'].value == null ? doc['victim.ip'] : doc['victim.instanceId']",
        "lang": "painless"
    },
    "missing": "N/A"
}
```